# touch Carousel scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, carousel

I want the carousel with scrollbar holder. I found the following location.

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/touchcarousel/#carousel-image-and-text

Downloaded from:

https://github.com/netwire88/jquery-touchcarousel

If i used only one item in the container the **scrollbar** and **prev** and **next** arrows will be displayed. How can we aviod??

Or

Any one can suggest other carousel like "http://www.amazon.com/". Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to use TouchCarousel? Only reason I ask is because it requires you to buy a license and there are plenty of free (and in my opinion better options) out there.

One I've used frequently is http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

If you look @ the "Add & Remove" demo, you will see that prev/next arrows are only shown if there are enough carousel items to need them.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah. I want to display the scrollbar in the bottom of the carousel like amazon. So only i choose it.

Comment: I already refer this slick carousel. Is it have scrollbar?? Sorry I didn't noticed?? Please.

Comment: Slick doesn't have a scrollbar no sorry, didn't realise this was a definite requirement. How about http://darsa.in/sly/?

Comment: but it haven't any download option.

Comment: Up the top you will see the "Download" section with 1.3.0 in big letters. There are two options - production or development. I believe you will use the production version.